# MySQL has filled hard drive - can I get some back?

Tags: mysql

I have an ancient web application that a few people still rely on. A year or so ago I discovered that the database that backs it had filled almost all of the disk space available. I deleted a lot of the no longer needed content from the database and that was when I learnt that MySQL doesn't deallocate disk space.

I was able to free up about 14Mb which was enough for Apache to write its log files.

It has limped along since and the users that have been using it have stubbornly continued to despite my gentle suggestion that they use the new thing I built that works a bit better!

Today something has eaten the magic 14Mb and everything has stopped working.

Is there anything I can do to reclaim some of the space from MySQL without killing all the data in it?

UPDATED with some of the details asked for in comments:

`du -hs /var/lib/mysql` : 30G

`df -h` : size 36G, used 34G, avail 0, use 100%

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version'`:  5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3

Comment: Since you mention apache log files also contributing to your woes and you don't mention your partition/volume  layout either, it sounds like everything is installed in a single volume and you might be able to free up space elsewhere. Those apache log files (and other logs) might be compressed or deleted altogether etc.

Comment: I have deleted all of the old .gz log files for apache, that was where I got the original 14Mb from, and yes, it is just a single volume - it was one of the first 'proper' web apps I built and I learnt a lot doing it, but I definitely didn't do it right. I'm just hoping to get it going again enough so I can finally get my last few users to get their data off!

Comment: A database server should be easy to relocate elsewhere with more space available.

Comment: If I could create a new machine with more space, how can I transfer the database without having enough space on the original server to dump into? The database is ~30Gb. That's a different question to what I've asked I suppose.

Comment: Did you used mysql's tool to compact the data ?

Comment: You can compact / optimize the tables using OPTIMIZE TABLE syntax from a mysql client, but you're going to need to back it up and the space required to accomplish this is a large proportion of your existing database. Please detail the mysql version, how big your mysqldata folder is, the storage capacity of your server etc.

Comment: I have added the size details - the app has been running mostly unattended by me for 3 years or so.

Comment: Also, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` reports "Table does not support optimize" and then complains about not being able to write a file (because the disk is full!)

Comment: You could safely delete the files in the apt cache in /var/cache/apt/archives and consider to check /boot for removing older kernel files. Both should give you some more space if you still not grabbed it ;-)

Comment: Already scrubbed those corners clean! It's a mess of a server really and not much hope. Like I said above, I learnt a lot making it!

Comment: Depending on the amount of RAM and size of the swap partitition you could initiate a RAM disk and move temporarily some stuff there while your maintenance work. But I guess you won't solve the problem finally without a second machine. With a database replication you might be able to move the services seamlessly to another machine.